# Undoing removal of methods in Squeak Smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

How do I undo the removal of a method in Squeak Smalltalk?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. 'World Menu'->'open'->'simple change sorter'
2. In the top-right pane, select the class from which the method was removed.
3. In the middle pane, select the removed method.
4. Right click on the method name, bringing up a menu
5. Select "versions"
6. When the versions tool comes up, select the top (most recent) version, which is the one you deleted.
7. Click the "revert" button

When you browse your class, you will see that the method is restored.

Comment: Wow, this is wild! Thanks Sean.

Comment: This is the magic of a live, open, dynamic system like Smalltalk :)

Answer (score 4):

If you use OmniBrowser and the Refactoring Tools you have unlimited undo/redo on all your code changes like in any other modern editor. Select in the context menu *Refactor* > *Undo*.

Comment: Thanks Lukas! After I finish [this epic tutorial](http://squeak.preeminent.org/tut2007/html/035C.html) I’ll learn how to install packages in Squeak and will give OmniBrowser a shot.

Answer (score 4):

You can open your changes file:

- Tools menu at the top of your screen.
- File List (which should open in the right place).
- In the upper right pane select the changes file (given an image called Foo.image, you'd look for Foo.changed).
- Hit the "recent changes" button, browsing as far back as the latest (top) snapshot.
- All method additions, alterations, deletions, DoIts are listed in the list that pops up.
- Select the method/s you want, right click (I can *never* remember the colours for mouse buttons) and "fileIn selections".

Comment: Cool! That’ll be handy when I’ve forgotten where the removed method came from. Thanks for showing me something new about Smalltalk.